# init.d start/stop scripts

Tags: linux, bash, daemon

I have to call a perl program in start/stop script. I have my perl program in path/to/program: /home/nuthan/server.
Now, my task is to create a start/stop script. i.e., need to call command **daemon -d -v -r perl /home/nuthan/server -l /tmp/k** on start and kill the pid on stop. I found too many scripts on net, i found this at http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-write-sys-v-init-script-to-start-stop-service.html. but I don't understand this, as I am new to Perl. Please help, where do i add the commands, or Am i wrong?

```
#!/bin/bash
# description: Foo server

# Get function from functions library
. /etc/init.d/functions
# Start the service FOO
start() {
    initlog -c "echo -n Starting FOO server: "
    /path/to/FOO &
    ### Create the lock file ###
    touch /var/lock/subsys/FOO
    success $"FOO server startup"
    echo
}
# Restart the service FOO
stop() {
    initlog -c "echo -n Stopping FOO server: "
    killproc FOO
    ### Now, delete the lock file ###
    rm -f /var/lock/subsys/FOO
    echo
}
### main logic ###
case "$1" in
start)
start
    ;;
  stop)
    stop
    ;;
 status)
    status FOO
    ;;
restart|reload|condrestart)
    stop
    start
    ;;
*)
    echo $"Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart|reload|status}"
    exit 1
esac
exit 0
```

Comment: Well I don't know anything at all about this script, and I have to admit I stopped reading after about 10 lines, but probably wherever it says `FOO`.

Comment: You don't need to not know perl not to understand this script, because it isn't perl. Like the shebang says, it's bash.

Comment: TLP ok its bash and not perl. Both seemed same to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is where you'd need to put the `daemon` command in the `start function`.

```
start() {
    initlog -c "echo -n Starting FOO server: "
    daemon -d -v -r perl /home/nuthan/server -l /tmp/k
    ### Create the lock file ###
    touch /var/lock/subsys/FOO
    success $"FOO server startup"
    echo
}
```

Generally `init.d` scripts should record the pid and `killproc` should know where to find the pid.

However there are so many ways that this could not work as expected, you'll be learning a lot about unix, perl and init.d scripts fixing it.